# Finding the derivative of this function with natural log and sums

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of this function with respect to alpha

$n \ln(\alpha + 1) + \alpha \sum \ln x$

The natural log and sum is confusing me.

Comment: The derivative is linear so each term in the sum can be differentiated independently. Note that since you are differentiating with respect to $\alpha$ that $\ln x$ is a constant.

Comment: If a factor has no alpha in it, it is a constant as far as differentiation with respect to alpha goes.  Do you know the chain rule, and do you know $d/dx( ln x) = 1/x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the chain rule, the derivative of $n\log (a+1)=\frac n{a+1}*\frac{d}{da}(a+1)=\frac{n}{a+1}*1$

$$\frac{n}{a+1}*1+\sum\log x=0\\
\frac{n}{a+1}=-\sum\log x\\
-\frac{n}{\sum \log x}=a+1\\
a_{MLE}=-\left(1+\frac{n}{\sum \log x}\right)$$

Comment: ^^Is that similar for natural log

Comment: Yes, here $\log$ means $\ln$